# Device Design using RFID, Transistors, and a Wet Sensor Element

Tags: transistors, rfid

I'm seeking advice on a circuit design that I hope will function as follows:

I am attempting to design an RFID device in which the Q-factor is dictated by a 'sensor-resistor' element which responds to the environment in some way. DC resistance of the sensor-resistor is on the MOhm scale, but the element contains water and so has capacitive behavior at high AC frequency.

I have a colleague who has successfully constructed such a device, except their sensor-resistor is dry. They experimented with a hydrated resistor element and found that the RFID chip had no response, presumably from the effect water has on high frequency impedance.

I've come up with a potential workaround but am not confident, as I lack an EE background. The idea is to integrate a transistor into the RFID chip and control gate voltage using a DC circuit containing the sensor-resistor (see below):

[image]

I'm wondering if (1) this approach makes any sense, (2) if the diagram I have drawn is correct or needs additional parts, and (3) how I should go about choosing an off-the-shelf transistor to build this device. Thanks very much!!

Disclaimer: I have an engineering background but limited EE knowledge. Apologies if I omit or mess up details, please ask/correct me :)